# F# and recursion problems

Tags: recursion, f#

I'm having two questions, one which concerns how the compiler behave, and one where I simple have looked me blind on my own code and need a little help to error tracing

Sorry for the rather big code block.

The first question the Right function will compile since it do adhere the type system, but at run time it will cast a stack overflow.

RightAssociative will not cast a stack overflow what is the difference?

The second question: The test below return "abbaa" and not "abba", I have tacked it down to the RightAssociative function and that it even though it end with a the single part of the "Or" (<|>) still use the map

```
let  error msg = 
    sprintf "Parsing error:\t\n%s" msg
    |> Error

type 'I Iter =
    abstract member Next : Result<'I,string> 
    abstract member Prev : unit              
    abstract member Show : unit // print for debugging

type  Parser<'output> = Parser of (char Iter -> Result<'output, string>)


let  run (Parser p) = p

let inline Atom expects =
    fun (input : char Iter) ->
        match input.Next with
        | Ok a when expects a ->
            Ok (string a)
        | Ok a ->
            input.Prev 
            sprintf "faild to parse %A" a
            |> error
        
        | Error msg -> 
            input.Prev
            msg 
            |> error
    |> Parser

let Or pat1 pat2 =
    fun input ->
        match run pat1 input with
        | Ok a -> Ok a 
        | Error _ ->
            match run pat2 input with
            | Ok a -> Ok a
            | Error msg -> 
                Error msg
    |> Parser

let  (<|>) = Or 


let And pat1 pat2 =
    fun input ->
        match run pat1 input with
        | Error msg -> Error msg
        | Ok a1 ->            
            match run pat2 input with
            | Ok a2 -> Ok (a1,a2)
            | Error msg -> 
                input.Prev
                Error msg
    |> Parser   

let ( <&> ) = And

let  Map f pat =
    fun input ->
        match run pat input with
        | Error msg -> Error msg 
        | Ok ret -> Ok (f ret)
    |> Parser

let rec Right pattern = pattern <&> (Right pattern) |> Map (fun (x : string, y) -> x + y) <|> pattern

let rec RightAssociative parser =
    let rec right (input: char Iter) = 
        (Map (fun (reg1 : string, reg2) -> reg1 + reg2) (parser <&> (Parser right))) <|> parser
        |> fun pattern -> run pattern input
    
    Parser right 
    

let aOrb = Atom (fun x -> x = 'a') <|> Atom (fun x -> x = 'b')

type iter =
    {   
        mutable prevs : char list
        mutable buffer : char list 
    }
with
    interface char Iter with
        member I.Next = 
            let n = List.tryHead I.buffer
            match n with 
            | None -> Error "reach end of stream"
            | Some c ->
                I.buffer <- I.buffer.Tail
                I.prevs <- c :: I.prevs
                Ok c
        
        member I.Prev =
            let p = List.tryHead I.prevs
            match p with
            | Some p -> 
                 I.buffer <- p :: I.buffer
                 I.prevs <- I.prevs.Tail
            | None -> ()

        member I.Show =
            printfn "prevs: %A" I.prevs
            printfn "buffer: %A" I.buffer

let right = RightAssociative aOrb
let test = { prevs = []; buffer = [for c in "abba" -> c] }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    match run right test with
    | Ok(asAndbs) -> printfn "Test passed with %s" asAndbs
    | Error(msg) -> printfn "Test on right failed with %s" msg

    1
```

Comment: Your code snippet migth be too long for anyone to fiddle with - and it also does not seem to compile when I copy it into a new F# Script file. Can you try making it self-contained and, if possible, remove some unnecessary aspects?

Comment: forgot something i think

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, the issue is that `Right` unconditionally calls `Right` recursively. This is because both the left and right arguments need to be evaluated before calling `<&>`:

```
let rec Right pattern = 
  pattern <&> Right pattern // <-- Calls 'Right' unconditionally here
  |> Map (fun (x : string, y) -> x + y) <|> pattern
```

You can fix this by definining a `Delay` helper that wraps the call in a function and only gets the parser when it is actually called with some input:

```
let Delay f = 
  Parser(fun i -> 
    let (Parser p) = f() 
    p i)

let rec Right pattern = 
  pattern <&> (Delay (fun () -> Right pattern))
  |> Map (fun (x : string, y) -> x + y) <|> pattern
```

I'm not sure about the second issue, but it's not related to recursion - there must be something wrong with your `<&>` and `<|>` operators. Try the following:

```
let right = (aOrb <&> (aOrb <|> aOrb))
let test = { prevs = []; buffer = ['a'] }
run right test
```

This succeeds and returns `("a", "a")` which does not sound right to me. If you replace `aOrb <|> aOrb` in the above with just `aOrb` then the parser fails as expected, so I suspect there is some issue related to `<|>`.

Comment: Thanks did fix the last part myself